# XCOPY source not working variables, Batch scripting

Tags: batch-file, copy, xcopy

I'm trying to write this script so that the selected folder (with all files and subfolders) would be copied to a new location.

XCOPY is giving me errors and I can't seem to figure them out.
My mkdir works without a problem.

Here's some code:

```
set src="%driveletter%\Users\TomP"

MKDIR \\lacie-2big\Public\backups\"Backup %klant%"
set dest="\\lacie-2big\Public\backups\Backup %klant%"

XCOPY /C /S %src% %dest%
```

I get 0 files copied.

---

**Solved with:**

```
set src="%driveletter%:\Users\TomP"
```

I forgot the `:`.

Comment: What errors are you getting? The Error Code and or Message?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with robocopy ?

```
robocopy %src% "%dest%" /MIR /Z
```

Comment: If I try robocopy the path is incorrect:
It uses: C:\Users\Tomp\Desktop\C\Users\Tomp\test

Comment: can you try xcopy with `set src=%driveletter%\Users\TomP\test\*` please ?

Comment: Error, file not found - *

Comment: But I'd like to continue with robocopy. I think it's just somesort of syntax error with quotations

Comment: I can see the real value of src ?

Comment: For me the src is not correct... If is "C:\Users\TomP\DesktopC\Users\TomP\test" then %driveletter% is "C:\Users\TomP\DesktopC". Can you try with `set src="C:\Users\TomP\test"` because I suppose that the path "C:\Users\TomP\test" and not "C:\Users\TomP\DesktopC\Users\TomP\test"